# Connection to .sdf database from sub dir of site in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix, sql-server-ce-4

I have a small website that I am building using ASP.NET web pages Razor Syntax. It has an SQL CE 4 database in the App_Data folder. The connection and getting records from the database works fine in pages that are in the root directory and the /Account subdirectory. However when trying to get data from the database in pages that are in other subdirectories, connection to the database does not work. I get an error: Connection string "Database.sdf" was not found.

It is using the connection string from the Web.config file in the root directory:

When I tried copying the root Web.config to the subdirectory I get the following error:

The entry 'Database' has already been added. (C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\SmallWebsite\subdir\web.config line 11).

At the moment I'm stumped and can't seem to find an answer either in msdn or google. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
nl

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Turns out all I needed to do was actually read the error message. In the root pages I was using code:

var db = Database.Open("Database"); to connect, and in subdirectories: 
var db = Database.Open("Database.sdf");

Once I removed the .sdf everything worked fine!

Thanks,
nl